# Как добавить данные из input в массив и записать в БД одной кнопкой?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Нужно добавить из скрытых инпутов массив в базу данных.

```html
 <form class="card-popup-wrapp cart__form form-send" method="POST" action="../func">

<input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="${name}">
                    <input class="js-cart-input-quantity" type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="${quantity}">
                    <input class="js-cart-input-price" type="hidden"  name="price[]" value="${price * quantity}">

<button class="btn-popup form__btn but" id="but" type="submit"> GO</button>

</form>
```

Мой PHP файл:

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($names); ++$i) {
$name = $names[$i];
$price = $prices[$i];
$quantity = $quantities[$i];



mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `zakaz` (`id`, `name`, `price`, `quantity') VALUES (NULL, '$names', '$prices', '$quantities')");
```

};

```
header('Location: /index');
```

Добавляется последний элемент всё время. Как быть?

Answer (score 0):

Надо поставить всем инпутам квадратные скобки в имена, т.е.

```
name="name[]"
name="quantity[]"
name="price[]"
```

На бэке будет не `$name, $price, $quantity`, а `$names, $prices, $quantities`

Дальше делаем цикл по любому из массивов

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($names); ++$i) {
    $name = $names[$i];
    $price = $prices[$i];
    $quantity = $quantities[$i];

   // ТУТ INSERT В БД
}
```

Comment: В таком случае в полях этих пишется "Array" и то один, даже если товара больше, чем 1

Comment: Ну ты же умный, ты же понимаешь, что надо писать в цикле? Или ты ждёшь чуда и что код сам за тебя разберётся что куда и как класть?

Comment: Я вот наверное и задал вопрос для того, чтобы узнать как это сделать, кхм.

Comment: Нет, ты задал совсем другой вопрос: У тебя в php скрипт из фронта не отправлялся массив, у тебя отправлялся только один элемент от каждого инпута. Теперь ты получаешь все элементы, как и хотел..... Ты не знаешь как в цикле пробегаться по элементам?

Comment: Хорошо. Здесь тогда еще вопрос. Как можно выполнить цикл, чтобы этот массив в несколько строк поместить в БД?

Comment: Если у тебя был совсем другой вопрос - тогда стОит отредактировать вопрос и детальнее описать его: что у тебя есть на фронте, что с него отправляется, в каком виде, показать больше кода на фронте, а не обрывок, как эти данные отображаются в php скрипте, что именно написанно в php скрипте (показать код), что ты заносишь, что ожидаешь и что происходит

Comment: "Как можно выполнить цикл, чтобы этот массив в несколько строк поместить в БД?" --- как обычно. любой foreach. Гадать любят гадалки, а без детального описания мало кто может помочь

Comment: Добавил кода в вопрос

Comment: Собсн, как я говорил - цикл.. Добавил в ответ..... хотя на самом делается всё  чуть по-другому, но на ткущем этапе достаточно этого

Comment: С запросом тоже проблемы, вставил то, что на данный момент есть

Comment: ну правильно надо вставлять $name, $price, $quantity

Comment: Хотелось бы пример что ли

Comment: Ну вот скажи, зачем написаны строки `$name = $names[$i];
    $price = $prices[$i];
    $quantity = $quantities[$i];` ? просто так? чтобы переменные были? чтобы сказать заказчику, что ты написал 34578 строк кода?  или это данные для вставки?  Ты немножечко поразмышляй, а не бездумно делай....... У тебя **уже был код для вставки**....какой ещё пример тут нужен. Посмотри в первую редакцию своего же вопроса

Comment: Не знаю что у меня было, во всяком случае оно не работало и не работает

Comment: Сочувствую.....

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482   тогда сюда.

Comment: ага, спасибо за помощь